# How can I copy data from CSV to a destination table based on column names?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Context**

I am receiving CSV files in S3, which do not always follow the same schema and/or order. For example, sometimes files look like:

```
foo, bar, bla
hi , 007, 42
bye, 008, 44
```

But other times, they can look like (`bar` can be missing):

```
foo,  bla
hi ,  42
bye,  44
```

Now let's say I'm only interested in getting the `foo` column regardless of what else is there. But I can't really count on the order of the columns in the CSV. so on some days `foo` could be the first column, but on other days `foo` could be the third column. By the way, I am using [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/) as a database.

**What I have tried to do**

I created a destination table like:

```
CREATE TABLE woof.meow (foo TEXT);
```

Then I tried to use Snowflake's [COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) command to copy data from the CSV into the table I created. The catch here, is that I tried to do the same way I normally do for Parquet files (matching by column names!) like:

```
COPY INTO woof.meow 
FROM '@STAGES.MY_S3_BUCKET_STAGE/'
file_format = (
  TYPE=CSV,
  COMPRESSION=GZIP,
)
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE;
```

But sadly I always got: `error: Insert value list does not match column list expecting 1 but got 0`

Some research lead me to this section of the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) (about `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME`) to discover CSV is not supported:

```
This copy option is supported for the following data formats:

- JSON
- Avro
- ORC
- Parquet
```

**Desired objective**

How can I copy data from the [STAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html) (containing csv file on s3)to a pre-created table based on column names?

I am happy to provide any further information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Copy Options (copyOptions)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table#copy-options-copyoption)

> MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_SENSITIVE | CASE_INSENSITIVE | NONE
>
> Definition
>
> String that specifies whether to load semi-structured data into columns in the target table that match corresponding columns represented in the data.
>
> This copy option is supported for the following data formats:
>
> - JSON
> - Avro
> - ORC
> - Parquet
> - **CSV (Preview feature - Open)**

---

```
COPY INTO woof.meow 
FROM '@STAGES.MY_S3_BUCKET_STAGE/'
FILE_FORMAT= (
  TYPE=CSV,
  PARSE_HEADER=TRUE
  -- ,...
)
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert CSV which is comma separated values file data into one text column ,to my knowledge your column order in your source data files should be same as column orders that you have created for target table in Snowflake which means if you have foo , bar and bla as columns in source csv file then your target  table columns should be also be created as separate columns , in same order as source csv files;
If you have unsure of what columns could come in your source file ; i would recommend you transform this file to JSON (that is my choice you can choose other option too like avro) and load that content into VARIANT column in Snowflake;
By this way you would not worry much about order of columns in source files , you would store data as JSON/AVRO into target table and would use JSON handling mechanism to convert JSON values into Columns.(Flatten the JSON to convert it onto relational table)`